# Client side validation vulnerabilities in GWT

Tags: validation, gwt

I am building a web application using GWT, and performing the validation of text boxes and other fields in client side using a simple java class.I am not sure that a user can bypass those validation during the running of that code.Please tell me the best secure way I can do the validation in forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you'll want to validate **both** on the client and on the server: On the client for immediate feedback to the user (convenience, optional), and on the server for security (must!).

In contrast to applications that use jQuery or similar on the client side, and a different language on the server side, the advantage you get with GWT is, that you may be able to reuse the same validation code for client and server validation.

Comment: +1 It should also be noted that the main reason to do client side validation is to reduce unnecessary calls to the server.

Comment: I have one doubt that when the method is called to server the calling is done through the java code and the java code is converted to javascript in GWT then what should be done if the javascriptcode is modified and the statement calling the server for validation is deleted.What should be done in this scenario for security.

Comment: @Amandeep: The user can only modify the client side code. Better: Imagine, that users can send absolutely *any* HTTP request they want (try e.g. the Firefox add-on [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/poster/) - they don't even have to use your GWT application to interact with your server! This is the reason, why all security checks have to be performed on the server side, too.

Comment: @Chris:Please tell me that I am performing the server side validation what is the flow of calling from GWT application to the server.

Comment: @Amandeep: I think, it would be best to open a separate question concerning the program flow of GWT validation, (where you can provide more details, and get more specific answers).

Comment: @Chris:I got the solution ,now I am validating on the server by sending the contents that user inputs in the textboxes and other controls in the button click event and interacting with database in the same event,and if user inputs wrong data then the response is sent back to client without interacting with database.It is a lengthy procedure though but served my purpose.Thanks for your help.Amandeep

Answer (score 3):

Javascript in browsers can be hacked/bypassed, so there is no secure way to do this. You should not rely on javascript to perform any security related functions.

You must do security checks on server it you want your app to be secure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short blog post on my view of Client vs Server Validation:

http://ashtoncthomas.blogspot.com/2011/03/gwt-validation-on-client-server.html

There are a few areas where you can validate and some balances such as sharing code between the client and server.

Do you validate before you create DTO's or after (if you do after then you can share some code but you can't trust the input)

I built a custom validation framework which makes it easy to bundle validation on client and server but every situation is different and so I recommend finding something that works for the majority of your projects or at least for your current one.

Answer (score 0):

Proper client side validation has been promised since 2006!
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=343
I'm not holding my breath on this one.

I've moved from fragile home-baked client-side validation to round-trip validation, where you submit a persist request with the entity in an invalid state. If you've got a validator running server-side, RequestFactory will send you a Set in Receiver.onViolation().

This has meant much less code for me, at the expense of a small delay in clients receiving validation results. It's still a lot faster than pure HTML forms.

Take a look at Validating Entities in:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html